# a problem when sending values from text file MPI

Tags: c, malloc, mpi

Hello there I'm new to mpi, can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int size, rank;
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  float val = 0.0;
  float *nums;
  int count = 0;
  char c;
  int chunk;
  chunk = count / size;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  if (size < 2 || size > 10) {
    if (rank == 0) {
      printf(
          "This program needs to run on a number between 2 and 10 of "
          "processes\n");
    }
  } else {
    if (rank == 0) {
      float *nums = malloc(count * sizeof(float));
      fp = fopen("NumbersForMPI.txt", "r");
      while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%f%c", &val, &c) > 0) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      fclose(fp);
      // printf("\nCount = %d\n",count);
      //  Allocate the necessary memory
      // Read the numbers into memory
      fp = fopen("NumbersForMPI.txt", "r");
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%f%c", &(nums[i]), &c);
      }
      fclose(fp);
      //for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //printf("%f\t", nums[i]);
      //}
      //printf("\n");
      //free(nums);

      for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        MPI_Send(&nums[i * chunk], chunk, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      }
    }

    else {
      float *nums = malloc(chunk * sizeof(float));
      MPI_Recv(nums, chunk, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      float rMin = 0;
      float rMax = 0;
      float rAvg = 0;
      float rSum = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > rMax) {
          rMax = nums[i];
        }
        if (nums[i] > rMin) {
          rMin = nums[i];
        }
        rSum += nums[i];
      }
      rAvg = rSum / chunk;
      MPI_Send(&rMin, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rMax, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rAvg, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rSum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    if (rank == 0) {
      float sMin = 0;
      float sMax = 0;
      float sAvg = 0;
      float sSum = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        float rMin = 0;
        float rMax = 0;
        float rAvg = 0;
        float rSum = 0;
        MPI_Recv(&rMin, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&rMax, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&rAvg, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&rSum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        if (sMax < rMax) {
          sMax = rMax;
        }
        if (sMin > rMin) {
          sMin = rMin;
        }
        sSum += rSum;
      }
      sAvg = sSum / size;
      printf("Maxmum number is : %f\n", sMax);
      printf("Minimum number is : %f\n", sMin);
      printf("Average is : %f\n", sAvg);
      printf("Sum is : %f\n", sSum);
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

I get this:

Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned

a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.

message mpiexec noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node **** exited on signal 8 (Floating point exception).

I was expecting to get the min max avg and sum

Comment: There are three divisions in your program, will you be able to find the one by zero?